# Weird looking spectrum. FSK and ASK combo?

Tags: modes, bandwidth, spectrum-analyzer

Does this look familiar to anyone ?

[image]

Comment: At 433.92MHz it could be any one of dozens of proprietary signalling protocols.  That's where all your wireless thermometers and countless other devices broadcast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no visible carrier (no peak in the middle), it can not be an AM/ASK signal, which has half of its transmit power on the carrier. This leaves PSK and FSK as the likely choices.

The two visible peaks indicate this is most likely a simple 2-FSK signal, and the higher magnitude of the upper peak means the transmit data has more ones than zeros.